# Apply style to boolean filter in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-grid

Filter for boolean field in kendo grid is as shown below:

[image]

I need to set the font-weight to normal and increase spacing between the content and radio button. Can anyone please suggest if it is feasible, if yes, then how ?

Will it be possible to edit the style of filter button as well ?

My code snippet for this column is as follows:

```
{field: "IsValid", title: "Valid Value", type: "boolean", 
                            template: kendo.template('#= IsValid? "Yes" : "No" #'),                            
                            filterable: {
                                messages: { info: "Select: ",  isTrue: "Yes", isFalse: "No" }
                            }}
```

I tried applying style in messages section as was shown in a sample but it didn't work out :

messages: { info: "Select: ",  isTrue: "Yes", isFalse: "No", style : "font-weight : normal;" }

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. we faced similar scenario. And we modified it with some CSS trick kept inside the style tags. To override the label inside the div to show those radio buttons. Currently it was like so due to bootstrap styles. Over ride it as like below.

```
.k-filter-menu div label
{
display:inherit !important;// instead of *inline-block*;
}
```